# Ajax, добавление поста без перезагрузки страни

Tags: php, ajax

Есть два скрипта: обычный html, где пользователь добавляет пост, и index.php, где пост добавляется в бд, ну и страница перезагружается.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм кода на Ajax, с помощью которого страница не будет перезагружаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как обычно любят тут говорить, "примеров в интернете множество". Обычно люди в наше время используют jquery для отправки аяксовых запросов.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#send-message').click(function () {
            var text1 = $('#text').val();
            $.post(
                'adding_message_to_bd.php',
                {text: text1},
                function(){
                    $('#messages').append('<p>message: '+text1+'</p>');
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <form action="javascript:void(0);">
        <textarea id="text"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="send-message">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="messages"></div>
```

В самом скрипте `adding_message_to_bd.php` никакую страницу рисовать не нужно в принципе, нужно только принять параметры, обработать их и вставить в базу данных **через подготовленные запросы PDO или mysqli**.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, для чего Вы выделили **жирным** фразу "через подготовленные запросы PDO или mysqli" ?

Comment: @Alex, потому что это самое важное, что ни в коем случае никогда нельзя забывать) Думаете, нужно еще вставить пояснение - как это делать?

Comment: я думаю это не самое важное и даже совсем не важное в ответе на просьбу *Подскажите, пожалуйста, **алгоритм кода на Ajax, с помощью которого страница не будет перезагружаться**.* Как дополнение к ответу разумно, но не как важная информация.